# sqlerr 1062 Duplicate entry 'x-y' for key 'abcd' which is a unique key of two int columns

Tags: php, mysql

I created a table in mysql(5.1.55) as following:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS xyz (
  intC1 int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  intC2 int(11) NOT NULL,
  intC3 int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (intC1),
  UNIQUE KEY abcd (intC2,intC3)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

And then I tried to insert a row (using php 5.3.6, mysql 5.1.55) as following:

```
insert into xyz (intC1, intC2, intC3) values (null,4, 14);
```

And I received the error 1062 as following:

"Duplicate entry '4-14' for key 'abcd'"

This error repeats whether there are any rows in the table or not.

Please help.

Comment: what do you think does **UNIQUE KEY abcd (intC2,intC3)**?

Comment: And the error is clear you are adding duplicate record and the unique key constraint is upset about it, make him happy and do not insert duplicate record.

Comment: If you get dupes in a empty table you either have a pending transaction or your table is corrupted. (Or you're running your code twice.)